# UserControl variable in Ajax site

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a single-page site that has an UpdatePanel. Within that UpdatePanel, there are UserControls that are dynamically loaded.

All linking between 'pages' (which are just UserControls) is done by using a WebMethod that changes a `Session` variable that stores the UserControl to load. The page reloads, with a new UserControl, and everything works great!

The downside to this methodology, however, is that I'm aware that `Session` variables don't scale well. Too many of them kicking around is not a good thing, so I've heard. I've unsuccessfully attempted to use different methods but not have been able to succeed. I'm looking to set the UserControl to load very early in the Page Lifecycle.

I've tried HttpContext.Current.Items, UserControl public properties and even UserControl HTML injection. It's just a big mess.

Is there a best practice for this type of scenario? Any helpful links or suggestions?

All is much appreciated.

**Clarity update** 
I'm looking to change the UserControl to be loaded by the C# code-behind file through either jQuery method calls or a Webmethod. Session variables work, but don't scale.

Answer (score 1):

I would use localStorage, you can store lots of information like this

```
localStorage.setItem('var', 'data');
```

and get the data back like this

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('var');
```

Comment: Ok, so how could I access this data in C#? Is local store not just equivalent in some form to a session variable (ie won't scale well)?

Comment: localStorage is a pretty powerful container for storing client side data in a similar way to sessions, but more flexible. If you are trying to keep server side data on the client, I suggest using a database to store that information.  You can access javascript through C# by printing your data directly into javascript variables/objects, but that is more code to deal with if you application scales.

Comment: Yes, I've just done some reading on it. It seems like overkill, as does the database solution, for what should be such a simple problem. I literally need one single string to pass through an `onClientClick` to the code-behind before the page reloads. Again, WebMethods with Session variables worked but I want to move away from Session vars.

Comment: Depending on the data, and how security is implemented, you could use POST or GET to pass the data from page to page. If the data needs to be more permanent than that I would use a database, unless C# has some specific functionality to handle what you are looking to do. Any jquery/javascript solution is going to require you to pass data back and forth from javascript.

Comment: The only piece of data that I require is the name of the UserControl to load and a query string. I'm simply simulating linking to another page. I've been using OnClientClick of buttons that fire off a JS method (using Ajax POST) that in turn changes the Session variables through a C# WebMethod (HttpContext.Current.Session = "SomeControl.ascx". The page, when reloading, then grabs the current value of this session variable.

Comment: I'm looking for a lightweight method of changing/grabbing this variable. I can't load UserControls in the WebMethod because you don't have access to them or any other page variables.